# Server's certificate is not trusted error on Chrome for Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, ssl-certificate

I'm able to import the certificate into Android via settings/security/trusted credentials without a problem and have tried this on Android 4.1, 4.4, and 6.x without success.  SSL cert is generated with v3_req and v3_ca via openssl.  We use the web app offline and neither the app manifest nor service workers will work without a "green lock".  With Chrome moving to require SSL for app manifest soon (and deprecating it in favor of service workers), this is pretty important.  The server is IIS 8 (also tried on IIS 7). I swear this worked in the past!  Any help would be appreciated.

Works fine in Chrome on Windows and Linux (able to import cert and get the green lock instead of red).  Firefox works fine on Android.

This is for an internal web server on a .local domain.